# Sales emails not being received

Tags: email

We have had several websites where the sales emails have not been received by the client or customer (configured in System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails).

We have no problems receiving any of them and often it's a matter of the store owner not getting the BCC/separate emails.

Does anybody have any recommendations with regards to server setup/changes in Magento to help with the reliability of sending emails?

We have looked at using [AShroder's SMTP Pro module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html) but before going down that road I'd be interested to hear opinions.

Comment: Often the problem is, that the mails are considrered as junk. To avoid this, sending the mails via a well configured SMTP is a good idea, the better alternative is to send the mails via a mail provider.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Do you have any good examples of this or is it a case of Google it? :)

Comment: You can have a look at an external provider for the smtp, like https://mailjet.com/ for example.

Comment: One of the great things about Ashley's extension is the self test that you can run.  GREAT way to sanity check that mails are getting through.  Also, by sending through gapps, you should be able to check your Sent mail to see if the mail is being sent out, regardless of whether it's getting soft- or hard- spamboxed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem of Magento itself.

But if you send mails directly via a mail delivery agent from your webserver, the configuration of this one might be neglected.

I am assuming you send via the standard Linux mail delivery.

You have the following options:

1. configure your mail system on the Magento server to use a well configured mail server for example of your ISP
2. use an extension - AShroder's SMTP Pro module would fit.

One interesting provider which promises (untested) to take a lot of effort that your mail is actually delivered is [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) - the module you mentioned also has a dedicated interface to Amazon SES.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I'll have to investigate further to find out how we have the mail settings configured but it looks like the module will be the best route and look at using the third party mail clients if we need to improve it further. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with a new site on Magento, and I requested the hosting company create a SPF record and that resolved the issue.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786

Otherwise, definitely use AShroder's SMTP Pro module.

Comment: +1 on the Ashroder module. I coupled this with a very small account at Socketlabs and all of my email woes were solved. SPF and DKIM/Domainkeys will work, too, but you have to host your own DNS... depends on your hosting provider.

Answer (score 3):

Another think is you need your own e-mail templates. If you use only the standard magento e-mail templates the emailserver think this is spam. => own e-mail templates

Comment: That's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

A great extension I have used in the past to resolve this issue and easily configure SMTP settings is

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html

Also allows to directly connect with Google which is nice.

Good Luck!